Microsoft Surface Precision Mouse wheel stops working after a few mins
I have a Microsoft Surface Precision Mouse.
I am running Debian 6.10.11 x86_64 GNU/Linux on a LENOVO X1 CARBON V6 2018.
When I start the computer and log in, the mouse works and its wheel works.
But after a while the wheel stops working, but the rest of the mouse functions.
When I run xev I don't see any events for button 4 and 5 (wheel) at that point, though intially in the first mins after logging in, the events are there on xev for button 4 and 5.
If I run sudo systemctl restart bluetooth to restart the bluetooth, then the wheel starts working again for a few mins before it stops again.
Not sure what is causing it to stop. On the screen events related to BTLE Precision Mouse disconnected and reconneded just before the mouse wheel stops working.
Not sure how to troubleshoot it any further.
Has anyone faced a similar issue? Any ideas how to see what is causing the wheel to stop working?
Below are some redacted logs

sudo dmesg | grep -i "mouse"

[-----.------] input: BTLE Precision Mouse Keyboard as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/XXXX:XXXX:XXXX.XXXX/input/input127
[-----.------] input: BTLE Precision Mouse as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/XXXX:XXXX:XXXX.XXXX/input/input128
[-----.------] input: BTLE Precision Mouse as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/XXXX:XXXX:XXXX.XXXX/input/input129
[-----.------] hid-generic XXXX:XXXX:XXXX.XXXX: input,hidraw4: BLUETOOTH HID v1.25 Mouse [BTLE Precision Mouse] on YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY


sudo dmesg | grep -i "bluetooth"

[-----.------] Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
[-----.------] hid-generic XXXX:XXXX:XXXX.XXXX: input,hidraw4: BLUETOOTH HID v1.25 Mouse [BTLE Precision Mouse] on YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY
[-----.------] hid-generic ZZZZ:ZZZZ:ZZZZ.ZZZZ: input,hidraw5: BLUETOOTH HID v1.34 Keyboard [Ergonomic Keyboard] on YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY


sudo libinput list-devices


Device:           Ergonomic Keyboard
Kernel:           /dev/input/event19
Group:            9
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Disable-w-trackpointing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         0.0

Device:           BTLE Precision Mouse
Kernel:           /dev/input/event15
Group:            10
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   button
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Disable-w-trackpointing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive custom
Rotation:         0.0

Device:           BTLE Precision Mouse Keyboard
Kernel:           /dev/input/event16
Group:            10
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Disable-w-trackpointing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         0.0


sudo X -version

X.Org X Server 1.21.1.11

X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0

Current Operating System: Linux ???? 6.10.11-1????-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.10.11-???? (2024-??-??) x86_64

Kernel command line: ima_hash=sha256 kfence.sample_interval=100 intel_iommu=sm_off pci=noats printk.devkmsg=on slab_nomerge lsm=landlock,lockdown,yama,loadpin,safesetid,integrity,apparmor,selinux,smack,tomoyo,bpf apparmor=1 panic=30 glinux-boot-image=default-20241122.00.04 earlycon=uart8250,io,0x3f8 console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=hvc0 console=tty0 splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles i915.enable_psr=0
xorg-server 2:21.1.12-1 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.42.2
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.


echo $DESKTOP_SESSION

cinnamon

